# Alternative for sample

Tags: r, loops, sapply

I have the following `sample` code that uses `sapply` which takes long to process (since executed many times):

```
samples = sapply(rowIndices, function(idx){
  sample(vectorToDrawFrom, 1, TRUE, weights[idx, ])
})
```

The issue is that I have to draw from the weights which are in the matrix, dependent on the indices in `rowIndices`.

Does somebody have a better idea in mind to draw from the rows of the matrix?

Reproducable example:

```
rowIndices = floor(runif(1000, 1, 100))
vectorToDrawFrom = runif(5000, 0.0, 2.0)
weights = matrix(runif(100 * 5000, 1, 10), nrow = 100, ncol = 5000)

timer = 0
for (i in 1:2500){
  ptm = proc.time()
  samples = sapply(rowIndices, function(idx){
    sample(vectorToDrawFrom, 1, TRUE, weights[idx, ])
  })
  timer = timer + (proc.time() - ptm)[3]
}

print(timer) # too long!!
```

Comment: Is `sapply` really the bottleneck? I doubt it.

Comment: Yea it is, because it's executed thousands of times.

Comment: See my updated question

Comment: Check this: `system.time(
  sapply(rowIndices, function(idx){
    sample(vectorToDrawFrom, 1, TRUE, weights[idx, ])
  })
)`. Here it is 0.1s. Thus, the time issue is not the sapply it's your loop. Do you want to run the sample function 2500 times?

Comment: I don't understand. The `timer` in my updated question only accounts for the `sapply`, and I would prefer a lower cumulated processing time.

Comment: Not really. Again, do you want to run the sapply-sample function 2500 times?

Comment: Yes I do want to execute that 2500 times

Comment: Then as Spacedman already said the loop is your bottleneck. Try `lapply(1:2500, function(x) {
  sapply(rowIndices, function(idx){
    sample(vectorToDrawFrom, 1, TRUE, weights[idx, ])})
})` or check this https://www.r-bloggers.com/lets-be-faster-and-more-parallel-in-r-with-doparallel-package/

Comment: What I am saying is that *the thing inside your sapply* is probably the bottleneck. Not the use of `sapply` itself. If you can't speed up the random sampling (or whatever it is you actually have in your real code) you are wasting your time.

Comment: Tried a `for` loop? Takes *exactly* the same amount of time. Because the loop control is minimal, and the time taken is in the sampling. Speed that up.

Comment: @Spacedman I see! ... So I'll probably have to resubmit another question asking for a `sample` alternative

Comment: One way to speed up `sample` is to call once and draw `n` times. What I mean by this is that `rowIndices` are replicated 10x on average. Instead of calling `sample` 10 times for the same row index, call sample once and draw 10 values (or however many you need). This gave me a 5x speed up in my tests

Comment: Can you post the code that does that.

Comment: Of course, in my original code, it matters from which row I draw. They are not made by `runif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a way I would speed up your code. One thing to note: the sampled value will not "match" with `rowIndices` though it would be trivial to get things in the right order. 2) You only store the last iteration, though maybe that is just because this a Minimal Reproducible example...

Basically you should only need to call `sample` once per value of `rowIndices` since `rowIndices` ranges from 1-99, that's 99 calls instead of 1000, which provides a huge speed up.

We can just sort the row indices before we start

```
rowIndices <- sort(rowIndices) ##sort the row indices and then loop
for (i in 1:15){
    samples = unlist(sapply(unique(rowIndices), 
        function(idx){
            sample(vectorToDrawFrom, sum(rowIndices %in% idx), 
                TRUE, weights[idx, ])
    }))       
}

Unit: milliseconds

expr
                      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 newForLoop      263.5668 266.6329 292.8301 268.8920 275.3378  515.899   100  a 
 OriginalForLoop 698.2982 705.6911 792.2846 712.9985 887.9447 1263.779   100   b
```

### Edit

The way to maintain the original vector ordering is to save the index or the orignal `rowIndices` vector. Then sort the row indices and proceed.

```
set.seed(8675309)
weights = matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), 
                 nrow = 5, ncol = 3, byrow = T)

rowIndices = c(2,1,2,4)
vectorToDrawFrom = runif(3, 0.0, 2.0)

set.seed(8675309)
##This is the origal code
sample2 = sapply(rowIndices, function(idx){       
  sample(vectorToDrawFrom, 1, TRUE, weights[idx, ])
})

rowIndx <- order(rowIndices)   #get ordering index
rowIndices <- sort(rowIndices) 

set.seed(8675309)
samples = unlist(sapply(unique(rowIndices), function(idx){
  sample(vectorToDrawFrom, sum(rowIndices %in% idx), TRUE, weights[idx, ])
}))

samples = samples[order(rowIndx)]
all(samples == sample2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Great suggestion. However, I need that 'match' of `rowIndices`. You said it's trivial to keep the matching? How would you proceed?

Comment: No, sorting doesn't work. For example `weights = matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), nrow = 5, ncol = 3, byrow = T)` and `rowIndices = c(2,1,2,4)` and `vectorToDrawFrom = runif(3, 0.0, 2.0)`. There it should only be possible by the first returned value to be `vectorToDrawFrom[2]`.

Comment: I think the result is correct, I have used your example here to try to illustrate

Comment: To fit my need, the result should be `[1] 1.9971544 1.2770329 1.9971544 0.3762992`. I need the original order of `rowIndices`, because I'm multiplying with a matrix afterwards.

Comment: Great suggestion with `order`. However, it still doesn't work and that it works with your example seems to be an artefact of the data and the seed you set. To see that it doesn't quite work, see this example, where I choose everything randomly: https://paste.ofcode.org/AeH5MtmDAnRNKyceVbg6jZ

Comment: However, I'm not really sure why it shouldn't work... Your code seems to do the absolutely right thing! Do you have any idea why the above pastebin doesn't work?

Comment: The example code is "failing" because we are comparing two different sampling strategies. In case 1 we reset the seed before each draw whereas in case 2 we reset the seed per unique `rowIndices` value. Therefore if we were to compare the first draw for each `rowIndices` value in case 2 with the values from case 1 they should match. N.B. case 1 should produce the same draw for any given `rowIndices` value, which it does.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I still have problems. It seems to not return the same thing as the original code does. Do you have a suggestion how I could make `sample` use the same seed everytime? Also all the times where it's called internally, because the `size` parameter is >1?

Comment: Your code isn't correct yet. You have to do the reordering! So in the end do `samples = samples[order(rowIndx)]`. Cost me a lot of time.. Please edit this into your answer.