# Sample draw in sapply without replacement

Tags: r, sample, sapply

How does one draw a sample within a sapply function without replacement? Consider the following MWE below. What I am trying to achieve is for a number in `idDRAW` to receive a letter from `chrSMPL` (given the sample size of `chrSMPL`). Whether a number from `idDRAW` receives a letter is determined by the respective probabilities, risk factors and categories. This is calculated in the sapply function and stored in `tmp`.

The issue is sample replacement, leading to a number being named with a letter more than once. How can one avoid replacement whilst still using the sapply function? I have tried to adjust the code from this question ([Alternative for sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771186/alternative-for-sample)) to suit my needs, but no luck. Thanks in advance.

```
set.seed(3)
chr<- LETTERS[1:8]
chrSMPL<- sample(chr, size = 30, replace = TRUE) 
idDRAW<- sort(sample(1:100, size = 70, replace = FALSE)) 
p_mat<- matrix(runif(16, min = 0, max = 0.15), ncol = 2); rownames(p_mat) <- chr  ## probability matrix
r_mat <- matrix(rep(c(0.8, 1.2), each = length(chr)), ncol = 2); rownames(r_mat) <- chr ## risk factor matrix
r_cat<- sample(1:2, 70, replace = TRUE) ## risk categories

# find number from `idDRAW` to be named a letter:
Out<- sapply(chrSMPL, function(x){
  tmp<- p_mat[x, 1] * r_mat[x, r_cat]
  sample(idDRAW, 1, prob = tmp)
})

> sort(Out)[1:3]
G B B 
5 5 5
```

Comment: I feel like the easy answer is *don't* use `sapply`with `sample` in it. Identify which numbers from `idDRAW` receive letters, and then sample that many letters without replacement in a single step, rather than one at a time. I'm very confused, however, since `charSMPL` has repetition you will still have repetition in `Out` even if the `idDRAW`s are unique.

Comment: The repetition of `charSMPL` is what I want for unique draws of `idDraw`  @Gregor --reinstate Monica-- .

Answer (score 0):

I managed with an alternative solution using a for loop as seen below. If anyone can offer suggestions on how the desired result can be achieved without using a for loop it would be greatly appreciated.

```
set.seed(3)
Out <- c()
for(i in 1:length(chrSMPL)){
  tmp <- p_mat[chrSMPL[i], 1] * r_mat[chrSMPL[i], r_cat]
  Out <- c(Out, sample(idDRAW, 1, prob = tmp))
  rm <- which(idDRAW == Out[i])
  idDRAW <- idDRAW[-rm]
  r_cat <- r_cat[-rm]
}

names(Out) <- chrSMPL
sort(Out)[1:3]
```